# Slack API slash command - returns 502_service_error after the webhook is successfully used

Tags: slack-api

I built a slash command that I run, my server responds using the webhook URL the slash command sends out, the message posts to the channel, but then Slack shows a private message saying "Darn - that slash command didn't work (error message: 502_service_error)"

What's going on that's making Slack think my command failed? I tried adding an immediate response and this error still happens.

The code is an AWS Lambda function, the Slash Command is calling an AWS API Gateway to access it.

Here's my Python code which uses `requests` to return the data -

```
response = requests.post(
    urllib.parse.unquote(response_hook), json={'attachments':[{'text': result, 'color': 'good'}], 'response_type': 'in_channel'},
    headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
)
```

Comment: did you reply the initial POST from slack with status code 200? anything other than 2xx might be treated as error.

Comment: Can you please post the code leading to this behavior? That'd make figuring out what's going on there way easier, especially as there are multiple possibilities how to reply to slash commands.

Comment: Added more details and the code I'm using to return data to the webhook.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ended up figuring out the answer after more digging. I needed to add a specific response at the end of my function that let Slack know the message was received successfully. Below is the Python code I used to do that which resolved the issue -

```
return { "isBase64Encoded": True, "statusCode": 200, "headers": { }, "body": "" }
```

You may have to enable Lambda Proxy Integration in your API Gateway settings for this to work, that was enabled by default for me though.

Comment: In addition to this, it could be a good idea to check if your request to Slack does not cause some validation errors. In my case the title of the Slack dialog, I was trying to create, was 2 characters longer than what was expected (the limit is 24). Take a look at "Top-level dialog attributes" paragraph in the [dialog implementation section](https://api.slack.com/dialogs#implementation)

Comment: I've been stuck at this for over a week. I thought I exhausted all responses! Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is correct, Slack expects a '200' response with a slash command. Using the included 'callback' argument in the handler function of the lambda that receives the slash command works also.

`callback(null);`

The first argument to the callback is an error, so pass 'null' if ok. 
[AWS doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html)
[Slack documentation](https://api.slack.com/slash-commands#responding_basic_receipt)